# upload photo from file or postman by image address in my drive

Tags: javascript, node.js, postman, backend

I have a schema like this:

```
const Person = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Name is a required field"],
    unique: [true, "Another Person with the same name already exists"],
    trim: true
  },
  friends: [
    {
      name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Every friend must have a name"],
        unique: [true, "Another friend with the same name already exists"],
        trim: true
      },
     photo: String,
     favoriteFood: String
    }
  ],
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now()
  }
});
```

I want to add an image for each friend, but I want to upload the photo from something like postman or a seeder file by adding image address in my hard drive in the request. because I have several friends, I have to make each photo specific for each friend. I want to do something like this in postman body or in a file as a seeder to fill database or add data to it.

```
{
"username": "aUsername",
"friends": [
   {
     "name": "friend1",
     "photo": "./home/user/photos/photo1.jpg",
     "favoriteFood": "Pizza"
   },
   {
     "name": "friend2",
     "photo": "./home/user/photos/photo2.jpg",
     "favoriteFood": "Sushi"
   },   
   {
     "name": "friend3",
     "photo": "./home/user/photos/photo3.jpg",
     "favoriteFood": "Hamburger"
   }
    ]
}
```

how can I create this feature in the backend?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const multer = require('multer');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, '/src/my-images');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, file.fieldname);
  }
});

app.post('/', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
  if (!req.file) {
    console.log("No file received");
    return res.send({
      success: false
    });

  } else {
    console.log('file received');
    return res.send({
      success: true
    })
  }
});
```

Comment: thank you, but it would be nice if you explain it a little.